# snakemake - dynamically set log for each rule

Tags: logging, snakemake

I'd like to set the log file (`log` directive) for each of the workflow rules dynamically, so it contains the rule name. I tried to use the `set_log()` function like I do with `set_params()`, but am getting a cryptic error. Here is what I tried:

```
logs_dir = config['logs_dir']

rule1:
    ...

rule2:
    ...

for r in workflow.rules:
    r.set_log(os.path.join(logs_dir, r.name + '.log'))
```

and getting: `AssertionError in file ... in line ...`
I am probably misusing `set_log`, but couldn't figure it out. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
Following the suggestions in the answers, I tried the following:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'b'

rule myrule:
    input:
        'a'
    output:
        'b'
    log:
        dummy = 'dummy.log'
    shell:
        """
        cp {input} {output}
        """

for r in workflow.rules:
    r.set_log(real=r.name + '.log')
```

Unfortunately, running it with `snakemake -s snakefile -j 1` resulted again in an unspecified Assertion Error.

Comment: All rules need to have the `log` defined, else you'll receive the error. your `rule all` is missing the `log: ` decorator which causes the problem.

Comment: I added the dummy log to rule all. Now I don't get the Assertion error, but snakemake tells me `Nothing to be done (all requested files are present and up to date).`. Although the file `b` does not exist. Why is that?

Comment: You can also use a try/except AssertionError block in the workflow.rules loop to only redefine the log for rules that have that dummy set

Answer (score 2):

The `set_log` function is defined [here](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/e03a3b42eea89d512290bf98ee7d77ce2e17447c/snakemake/rules.py#L690) and I think it eventually runs into [this assertion](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/blob/e03a3b42eea89d512290bf98ee7d77ce2e17447c/snakemake/rules.py#L843) that throws this very-not-informative `AssertionError`. The way to fix it is to add an inline log definition to each rule:

```
logs_dir = config['logs_dir']

rule1:
    log: "rule1.log"
    ...

rule2:
    log: "rule2.log"
    ...

for r in workflow.rules:
    r.set_log(os.path.join(logs_dir, r.name + '.log'))
```

which unfortunately defeats the purpose of looping through and setting logs (if I'm understanding what you want to do here correctly). I recently ran into a very similar issue with setting threads without defining a `threads` value in each rule. Kind of annoying coming at it from this perspective but I think there is good reason behind this behavior.

One way you might be able to still avoid writing `log: 'rule_name.log'` in every rule would be using [rule inheritance](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#rule-inheritance) although I'm not totally sure how passing the names and wildcards would work. If you get something like this working please let me know.

Comment: Using rule inheritance will not work for assigning a default `log`. You can't overwrite the execution step (`shell`, `script`, ...) with rule inheritance. So you would be stuck with a 1:1 relationship between individual rules and their parent rules, from which they could inherit the log file.

Comment: Thanks, please see my update to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Ulthran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856468/11318472) you could also set a dummy log (with the same name) for all rules and then simply add the "real" log dynamically via loop:

```py
rule rule_name:
    ...
    log:
        dummy="logs/will-be-overwritten.txt",
    shell:
        """
        echo 'fake log' > {log[0]}
        echo 'real log' > {log.real}
        """


for r in workflow.rules:
    print(r.name)
    r.set_log(real="logs/" + r.name + ".log")
```

Note that this will create problems if you rule contains wildcards: If you do not handle the wildcards in your dynamically-added-log, then I don't know what will happen. Either Snakemake will throw an error or it will use the same logfile for all instances of the rule. I can only speculate that the potential existance of wildcards is one reason for the assertion error.

Comment: Thanks, please see my update to the original post.